# Extrapolate time series data based on Start and end values, using Python?

Tags: python, time-series, extrapolation

I have an excel sheet with values representing start and end_time of a time series data, as shown below. Times are in seconds.

```
+------------+---------+-------+
Start_Time   End_Time  Value
0            2      A
2            3      B
3            9      A
9            11     C
```

I want to extrapolate the values between start and end_time and display the values for each second.

`+---------+------+
    Time   Value
    0      A
    1      A
    2      A
    3      B
    4      A
    5      A
    6      A
    7      A
    8      A
    9      A
    10     C
    11     c`

Any help to implement it in Python will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup

You should find how to read your excel sheet with pandas [easily](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), and options will depend on the file itself, so I won't cover this part.
Below is the reproduction of your sample dataframe, used for the example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Start_Time': [0, 2, 3, 9],
                   'End_Time': [2, 3, 9, 11],
                   'Value': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C']})
>>> df
Out[]:
   End_Time  Start_Time Value
0         2           0     A
1         3           2     B
2         9           3     A
3        11           9     C
```

#### Solution

```
(pd.Series(range(df.End_Time.max() + 1), name='Value')  # Create a series on whole range
   .map(df.set_index('End_Time').Value)                 # Set values from "df"
   .bfill()                                             # Backward fill NaNs values
   .rename_axis('Time'))                                # Purely cosmetic axis rename
Out[]:
Time
0     A
1     A
2     A
3     B
4     A
5     A
6     A
7     A
8     A
9     A
10    C
11    C
Name: Value, dtype: object
```

#### Walkthrough

Create the whole "Time" range

```
s = pd.Series(range(df.End_Time.max() + 1))

>>> s
Out[]:
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      9
10    10
11    11
dtype: int32
```

Use "End_Time" as index for `df`

```
>>> df.set_index('End_Time')
Out[]:
          Start_Time Value
End_Time
2                  0     A
3                  2     B
9                  3     A
11                 9     C
```

Map df values to corresponding "End_Time" values from `s`

```
s = s.map(df.set_index('End_Time').Value)

>>> s
Out[]:
0     NaN
1     NaN
2       A
3       B
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     NaN
9       A
10    NaN
11      C
dtype: object
```

Backward-fill the `NaN` values

```
s = s.bfill()

>>> s
Out[]:
0     A
1     A
2     A
3     B
4     A
5     A
6     A
7     A
8     A
9     A
10    C
11    C
dtype: object
```

Then `rename_axis('Time')` only renames the series axis to match your desired output.

Note that this works here because you use **excluding** `Start_Time`.
If you were using **including** `Start_Time` (where `Value` really starts at `Start_Time`, which is more common) you should change `End_Time` to `Start_Time` and `bfill()` to `ffill()` (forward-fill).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1 for the walkthrough. Yes, I know how to use pandas to read excel.